# Ones in the coefficient matrix when calculating least squares

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

The function `numpy.linalg.lstsq` can be used to calculate an approximated function for some points x and y. On [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) there is given an example:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
>>> A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
>>> A
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.]])
>>> m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
```

The question is, why do we have to create the matrix `A` and then add ones after each single `x` parameter? Why is it not just possible to pass the array `x`?

Comment: `x` would only get you a trend, passing through the origin (in these dimensions it is easy to visualise the results graphically). Unless you have good reasons to assume that when `x` is zero, `y` is zero also, you would probably want an intercept. This requires a constant factor in the design matrix. The least-squares approach is explained quite well [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can rewrite the line equation as y = Ap, where A = [[x 1]] and p = [[m], [c]].

[Taken from the document you linked](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

This just another way to write

y = m*x + c*1 = m*x + c

which is the dot product of a row and a column vector. I cannot give you a reason in regards to the design decision that caused this to be the way it is. I think it is a good thing, though, as for example force torque sensor calibration procedures require you to fit what you measured without an offset (as in: c = const. = 0). By replacing

```
 A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
```

with

```
 A = np.vstack([x, np.zeros(len(x))]).T
```

you will be able to force the fit to go through the origin. Neat for some engineering aspects, especially for the qualification of components.